# Cannot make unordered_map work

Tags: c++

I have written fairly simple code to check out unordered_pair

```
// unordered_map example
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
int main (){
    std::unordered_map<double, double> mymap = {
        {5,2.3},
        {7,34},
        {4,12}
    };
    std::cout<<":::: unordered_map ::::"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"5 ->"<<mymap[5]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"7 ->"<<mymap[7]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"4 ->"<<mymap[4]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Done ! ";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error

```
unordered_map.cpp:5:37: error: non-aggregate type 'std::unordered_map<double, double>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
        std::unordered_map<double, double> mymap = {
                                           ^       ~
1 error generated.
Compilation failed
```

I am working on OSX and using geany.
Build command in Geany is :

```
g++ -Wall -c "%f"
```

Comment: You need (at least) `c++11`: `g++ -Wall -c "%f" -std=c++11`.

Comment: hey it works with this thanks :) i was hoping there could be another solution to this. is there a way to use associative containers in older standards ?

Comment: You have [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) if you want associative container. The difference with `unordered_map` is that `map` keeps the element ordered according to the key and thus you have different complexity for access, delettion, ...

Comment: I was trying to use `unordered_map` because it is faster than `map`. However, using `map` without `-std=c++11` still gives me same error as above. Is there a way to work arround it or other associative containers valid for older standard?

Comment: `map` is valid for older standard, but you don't have access to `initializer_list` prior to `c++11` so you need to add the element one by one in your map.

Comment: @hadi-k nope, initializer lists are from C++11 too.

Comment: @Holt can you give me a simple example of how to add the element one by one?

Comment: You simply first declare the map `std::map<double, double> mymap` and then use `operator[]` to add the element: `mymap[5] = 2.3; mymap[7] = 34`.

Comment: @Holt do you mean  `mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',100) );`? I will give this a try

Comment: oh this is great. Thanks :) .  I will use this :)

Comment: @hadik Both version would work.

Comment: @Holt Thanks a bunch. Now it is working fine and I learned quite a bit here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unordered_map` was introduced in the C++11 standard. If your g++ version supports it, you can enable c++11 standard with option `-std=c++11`

> is there a way to use associative containers in older standards

`std::map` is an associative container. It exists in all c++ standards.

> I was trying to use unordered_map because it is faster than map

`unordered_map` is faster in some cases. `map` is faster in other cases. Don't assume one way until you have measured.

> However, using map without -std=c++11 still gives me same error as above

That's because you use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which also requires c++11.

The old way of initializing a map:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m[1] = 3;
m[2] = 2;
m[3] = 1;
```

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of) has a neat template for similar syntax to list initialization:

```
map<int,int> next = map_list_of(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,6);
```

Comment: This is great thanks a bunch. The answers were very helpful and informative. :)